# how to deal with replication lag in microservices

Tags: microservices, lag, database-replication, distributed-system

I have following system:
[image]

In my system two different sources can cause creating specific type of event.
when I'm getting a delete event I'm gonna remove it from the db and then create another event with the type deleted.

When I'm getting second event from the second source I first check if I have an releative entity in the db and if yes I'm gonna create update event if not I'm gonna create delete event. due to replication lag in mongodb sometimes even if I have deleted entity from the db I can still see it in db and it causes inconsistency in my microservice.
I was wondering how can I deal with this issue except for reading from the primary.

Answer (score 0):

The specific solution for your problem could depend on many things, but essentially you need to [reconcile all the events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency#Conflict_resolution) if you want to reach strong consistency eventually.